# What can I do if my program stops running at the begin statement and forces me to click run again?

Tags: delphi

[image]

I have tried debugging, but because I'm a beginner I can’t seem to find the problem. I have a feeling it has to do with the text highlighted in red.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)

Comment: How are you starting the program in the debugger? Which menu are you using? It sounds like you are maybe starting the debug session using the "Step Into" or "Trace Into" menu instead of the "Run" menu. The "text highlighted in red" is saying that a breakpoint was reached, do you actually have a breakpoint on the `begin` statement? Have you read Delphi's [Overview of Debugging](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Overview_of_Debugging) documentation yet?

Comment: Start the program by pressing F9 -- not F8, and not F7. **Update:** No, you are starting it the right way. The problem, I realise now, is that you have put a breakpoint (the red disk) on the `begin` line. To remove it, put the caret on this line and press F5. You can also simply click the dot to remove it. (Third way: Use Shift+Alt+B to go to the breakpoint list and remove it there.)

Comment: (And, you can also choose to continue in spite of the breakpoint. Just press F9 to continue as usual. In addition, you may be interested in the [Print Screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Print_Screen) key.)

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if you have breakpoints from a previous session (or in the CPU window) and they are out of sync. This can also happen if you have shifted your code to a different drive or folder. They are not visible, but the debugger has to break at the nearest line.

To fix

1. Click on View / Debug / Breakpoints  or Ctrl+Alt+B
2. Delete All Breakpoints

**EDIT**
The `project.dsk` file stores the `breakpoints` as an absolute path to the filename.  If the project is shifted so that the drive or folder change, the breakpoints remain pointing to the non-existent file.  From my experience, the IDE then compensates by breaking at the first line of the project.